# Appended <Button> not functioning JQuery

Tags: jquery, button, append

I am using the .Append() method of JQuery to append buttons to an unordered list, and for some reason the appended button will not call its function when clicked. I inserted the same button using HTML, and it worked fine, but for some reason the appended button will not run. Is there a way to get them to work, or do I just have to work around it?

```
    $("#requestDisplay").append(<button class='requestRemovalButton'>" + "Remove Request" + "</button>);
```

Vs in the HTML

```
    <button class="requestRemovalButton">Remove Request</button>
```

The latter will run the function, however the former will not work, here is the function I was using to test the buttons.

```
    $(".requestRemovalButton").on( "click", remove);

    function remove() {
        alert( "The request is being removed, please wait." );
    }
```

Thanks for any advice you may have.

Comment: The way you're calling `.on()` will only add the event listener to `.requestRemovalButton` elements that exist at the point you call `.on()`.

Comment: I don't know if it's a copypaste error, but your code is missing some quotes. It should be `.append("<button class='requestRemovalButton'>" + "Remove Request" + "</button>");` (so there's a quote before the opening `<button` and after the `</button>`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the button is added dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler like:-

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('#requestDisplay').on('click', '.requestRemovalButton', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert( "The request is being removed, please wait." );
});
```

Comment: I changed the format, but it still isn't working for the appended buttons. For clarification, when clicking the appended buttons, instead of giving the alert, it just refreshes the page.

Edit: Nevermind, it is working, I was just clicking the wrong button. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It seems to working. Please have a look at this [`Fiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/qtRGB/). I think you need to use `event.preventDefault()` here to prevent refreshing the page.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to favor creating proper elements with event handlers :

```
var button = $('<button />', {
    'class' : 'requestRemovalButton',
    text    : 'Remove Request',
    on      : {
           click: remove
    }
});

$("#requestDisplay").append(button);
```

and it the button is inside a form, you have to prevent the default action of submitting that form:

```
function remove(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert( "The request is being removed, please wait." );
}
```